# Frame of UIView in UITableViewCell one pixel shorter in height

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout

I have a prototype cell I was adding some constraints to and noticed the values were always off when adding top and bottom spacing. Upon further investigation, I noticed that while the cell height shows 90, if you click inside the cell and select the UIView, it shows the height as 89. No matter what I set the height of the cell to, the view is one less and so I can't actually lay out my constraints correctly as it thinks its always got one less pixel to work with. Any idea why this would be happening? Something to do with the separator?

Comment: Have you checked to see if the issue still exists when you remove the separators?

Comment: i haven't because i definitely want the separators. i was under the impression the row height could be independent of the separator

Comment: I had the exact same problem in interface builder, and was unable to find the solution. I tried removing all constraints and adding them again, but with the same result. I ended up solving all autolayout issues in code instead, using this super simple library: https://github.com/jrturton/UIView-Autolayout

Comment: good to know I'm not the only one! ill check out that library, thanks!